# discrete random variable PMF

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables

suppose You rented a house and realtor gave you 5 keys, one for each of the 5 doors of house. unfortunately all keys look identical. so to open the front door, you try them at random.

=> Find the  PMF (probability mass function) of the number of trials you will need to open the door, under the following supposition :

i. after an unsuccessful trial, you mark the corresponding key, so you never try it again

ii. at each level you are equally likely to choose any key

Comment: actually I am new to probability and I feel a lot of trouble to understand the problem. I hope U people will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We mark bad keys:** The simplest way to look at the problem is the correct key is equally likely to be the first key you try, the second, and so on. So if $N$ is the number of trials needed, we have $\Pr(N=1)=\Pr(N=2)=\Pr(N=3)=\Pr(B=4)=\Pr(N=5)=\frac{1}{5}$.

Perhaps you are using the notation $f_N(k)$ for the probability that $N=k$. Then you could write $f_N(k)=\frac{1}{5}$ if $k=1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, or $5$, and $f_N(k)=0$ otherwise.

One can also do the problem more slowly. The probability that the first key opens the door is fairly clearly $\frac{1}{5}$, for there is only $1$ good key, and all keys are equally likely to be the good one.

In order to open the door with the second key, two things must happen: (i) The first key you try doesn't work and (ii) the second one does. The probability the first doesn't work is $\frac{4}{5}$. If the first doesn't work, then the probability the second does is $\frac{1}{4}$, since you have marked the first key. So the probability you get a failure and then success is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}$. This simplifies to $\frac{1}{5}$.

A similar argument shows that the probability of failure on the first two, followed by success, is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$, which again simplifies to $\frac{1}{5}$.

And so on! We get the same answer as with the first solution, but with more work needed.

**We don't mark keys:** Here $N$ can take on the values $1$, $2$, $3$, and so on *forever*.

The probability that the first key works is $\frac{1}{5}$.  So $f_N(1)=\frac{1}{5}$.

To get $N=2$ we need (i) failure on the first trial and (ii) then success. The probability of this is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5}$. Since we are not marking the key, our probability of success on any trial, given we have failed before, remains at a constant $\frac{1}{5}$. So $f_N(2)=\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5}$.

You should use the same idea to calculate $f_N(3)$. In general, we will find that
$$f_N(k)=\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{5}.$$

Comment: thanks. u mean pX(x) = { 1/5 , whan x = 1,2,3,4,5 but it is the answer of second part. what about first part?

Comment: Sorry to disturb U again . can u explain these notations f_N(2)=\frac{4}[5}\cdot\frac{1}{5}

Comment: is this the geometric random variable?

Comment: ok thanks . thanks . U know U solved a bigger problem for me

Comment: You are welcome. I only solved the problem as stated. (Had not noticed the second "with replacement" part until posting first reply. By the way, the system does not like long strings of comments, so I am deleting mine.